# Calling new operator on Generic type with parameter constructor

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core

I have the following class which is responsible for sending the response to the client from our service.

```
public class ServiceResponse
{
    public ServiceResponse()
    {
        Errors = new ErrorResponse();
    }
    public ServiceResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode, ErrorResponse errors = null)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Errors = errors ?? new ErrorResponse();
    }

    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get;  }
    public ErrorResponse Errors { get;  }
}

public class ServiceResponse<TResponse> : ServiceResponse
{
    public ServiceResponse() { }
    public ServiceResponse(TResponse response, HttpStatusCode statusCode, ErrorResponse errors = null) 
        : base(statusCode, errors)
    {
        Response = response;
    }

    public TResponse Response { get;}
}
```

We also use this one in the exception handling behavior class like the below, where we handle exceptions and send service responses based on the errors . However, I get the [compilation error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0417) , if I try to use a new with generic type and passing a parameter to the constructor

> 'TResponse': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a
> variable type

```
   public class ExceptionHandlingBehaviour<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    where TResponse : ServiceResponse, new()
{
    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        try
        {
            return await next();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            var response = new TResponse (HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            //var response = new TResponse { HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Message = ex.Message }; //Works with public setter
            return await Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
```

We would like to prevent setting StatusCode, Errors from out side and decided to go with private fields and exposed them via Constructor.

**Is there a way to achieve this without exposing the property to public?**

Comment: The only thing you can do is add a type constraint of `new()` to `TResponse` which would allow you to call the parameterless constructor. Otherwise, you're going to need a different way to create the service response objects.

Comment: Note: `return await Task.FromResult(response)` is entirely pointless. Just write `return response`

Comment: @DavidG Yes I did that. I forgot to put the full code which already contains `new()`, Just updated the code, it has no impact

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new parameter to the method that is of type `Func<HttpStatusCode, string, TResponse>` - a function that takes a `HttpStatusCode` and a `string`, and gives you a `TResponse`.

```
public async Task<TResponse> Handle(
    TRequest request, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken, 
    RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next
    Func<HttpStatusCode, string, TResponse> errorResponseFactory)
{
    try
    {
        return await next();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {               
        var response = responseFactory(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        return response;
    }
}
```

The caller, which knows exactly what `TResponse` is, would pass in `(x, y) => new FooResponse(x, y)` for this new parameter. Of course, it doesn't have to, so unlike calling the constructor, you are not guaranteed a new instance (or any instance at all) when you call `errorResponseFactory`, but I think that doesn't really matter in this context. If the caller wants `null` as the error response (`(x, y) => null`), you'll just return it null.

Comment: `Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)` this method is an MediatR pipeline behavior contract `IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
` and unable to provide additional parameter in the implementer

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan Well, you just need a `Func<HttpStatusCode, string, TResponse>` _some way_. How about adding it as a field of `ExceptionHandlingBehaviour`? And initialise it in the constructor or somewhere else.

Comment: Well, in that case I  need to supply the errorResponseFactory from the calling. However, we could not able to do something like `new ExceptionHandlingBehaviour(responseFactoryFunc)` as it was automatically registered by other library. Let me try, but I got your idea of injecting factory to that produces the specific type from generic one.